# I'm trying to knit a Word doc in R but I get an error in file (file,"rt")?

Tags: r, rstudio

This is my code below. I tried knitting my r mark down but it says

> Error in file(file,"rt"): cannot open the connection.

I don't know what this means; please put in layman's terms as to what I can do to resolve it. It indicates the first line is the problem.

```
Information<-read.csv("UnemploymentRateandPopulationGrowthRate.csv")
View(Information)
View(data)
dim(data)
Newdata<-data[-c(1:6),-c(3:20)]
View(Newdata)
merge(Information,Newdata,by="year")
MergingInformation<-merge(Information,Newdata,by="year")
View(MergingInformation)
plot(Fatal.Crashes~Unemployment.Rate....+Population.Growth.Rate....,data=MergingInformation)
plot(Fatal.Crashes~Unemployment.Rate....,data=MergingInformation)
plot(Fatal.Crashes~Population.Growth.Rate.....,data=MergingInformation)
```

Comment: Could you provide the code you are executing and well formatted here? Also the complete output log for the error will work

Comment: |......................                                           |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................................                      |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1


processing file: Workstuff.Rmd

Quitting from lines 14-26 (Workstuff.Rmd) 
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> read.csv -> read.table -> file
Execution halted

Answer (score 0):

File paths in your script are relative, try changing them by absolute paths and check if that works. The problem is related that working directory path and kinit path could be different.

A way to check that is using `getcwd()` in your script and checking if its working as you expected.

Comment: I'm confused. Sorry.

Comment: When you defining a script, `.rmd` file or whatever, all the files you are using/calling from your document must exist. Seems like one of the file paths you are providing are not relative to your `.rmd` doc. One solution is using absolute paths if you don't need to share your script across environments.

Comment: Another solution is moving all the files called inside the `.rmd` inside the same working dir of your script.

Comment: I tried normalPath(data filename) but when I tried knitting it once more, it still didn't work.